# Query with codeigniter 3 and dynamodb

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-dynamodb, jquery-filter

How do I make a query in Codeigniter 3 with dynamodb and in addition include an index?

In my example I get the following error:

> 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'hashKeyValue' failed to
>   satisfy constraint: Member must not be null

This is my example :

```
function obtener($fecha_registro) {

   $client = new AmazonDynamoDB(); 
   $response = $client->query( array(

     'TableName' => 'nom_table',
    'KeyConditionExpression' => 'id_registro = :v_hash and fecha_registro = :v_range',
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  array (
        ':v_hash'  => array('S' => '148537355319'),
        ':v_range' => array('S' => $fecha_registro)
    )
));


     print_r($response);
        if ($response->status == '200'){
            return $response->body->Items;
        } else {     
            print_r($response);
        }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to fetch related item from DynamoDB using Core Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381937/unable-to-fetch-related-item-from-dynamodb-using-core-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Only Reason you are getting this Error is :

> Amazon DynamoDB is not handling `empty` or `null` attributes.

As per [DynamoDB Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) :

> Attribute values cannot be null.

The Same issue is Raised at [AWS Developer Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=90137) also.

**Solution :**

Before passing your variable `$fecha_registro` to function `obtener()`,
You need to check whether the passed variable is `Non Empty` or `Not Null`

For your scenario just add a check before calling your function as below :

```
if(isset($fecha_registro) && ($fecha_registro != '' || $fecha_registro != NULL)){
     obtener($fecha_registro);
}
```

Comment: @Dave, You should Keep habit of upvoting and accepting the answers once you found your question resolved. :)